# ng2-chart with plugin trim outside labels- pie chart

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

This is my import for plugin:

```
import * as outLabels from "chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels";
```

This are my options:

```
 this.chartOptions = {
      responsive: true,
      legend: {
        position: "right",
        display: true,
        labels: { fontColor: "black" },
      },
    };
```

And this is the html:

```
<div class="chart" >
    <canvas
    style="width: 1000xp !important;"
      baseChart
      [data]="chartData"
      [labels]="chartLabels"
      [chartType]="chartType"
      [options]="chartOptions"
      [colors]="chartColors"
      [legend]="chartLegend"
      [plugins]="chartPlugins"
      
    >
    </canvas>
  </div>
```

This is the result:

[image]

Can I prevent that trim side effect in the outsided labels? And how?

Answer (score 0):

probrably it will help you.
It's a bug of ng-charts:

layout: {
padding: {
left: 20,
right: 20,
top: 60,
bottom: 60
}